# How to stop cookie manipulation for HTML to JSP page redirection?

Tags: html, session-cookies

I am trying to redirect my user from a html page to a jsp page which has been deployed on tomcat/webapps using .war file.

While doing so, I am also sending the session information of the user as an hidden parameter via POST method.

With the help of **burpsuite** tool(security testing tool) one can easily manipulate the cookie and change the username of the user logged in. How will I be able to block such kind of cookie manipulation?

Comment: You can't control/prevent what the client is sending. But why is it important what the browser is sending for a "username" cookie? A session cookie should only contain the id of the session to use (which holds all the information on the server side).

Comment: My project's security testing team has raised this concern, when we click on the link and during the page redirection they are able to change username(using their tool) and its a major security concern for the product.

Comment: Why do you save the username in a cookie? The username shouldn't be the only information to identify the user. Usually you use other techniques like sessions or JWT. This way either no information is stored in a client/browser or the data which *is* stored cannot be changed without breaking the integrity of the stored data (like using a cryptographic signature). Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the system you are building, where/how there is a redirect involved and which cookies you are sending between the client/browser and the server.

Comment: Hi Progman, I am not using cookie's explicitly. There are two different application deployed on the same tomcat/webapps with war file.

Comment: From the HTML page of application A , i am redirecting to JSP page of application B and passing the user name as hidden parameter in the POST request. 
Sample code as below:

`<form name="myForm" action="http://<ip address>:8081/applicationB/LandingPageController/home" method="post" id="formDT">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="inputText" value="${user.name}" >
<input type="submit" value="Got to B" id="pageb">
</form> ` 
Testing team is able to change username param in between redirection of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control/prevent what the browser/client is sending, so do not consider the data received as fact/true. Your application shouldn't just look at the username and say "oh, it's the admin user, I show the whole admin area".

To prevent tampering the data originated from the server or at least detect changes, you use encryption or digital signatures. With encrypted data, it is not possible to change the data. You don't know how to decrypt the data and encrypt the changed data correctly since you don't have the encryption key to do so. With signed data you can still read the data but the signature makes sure that you can detect, if the data has been changed.

In your case, you can use a JWT instead of just the username. The JWT contains a digital signature which is used to check if the data has been changed. Your "testing team" can change the data but your server can see immediately that it has been changed and reject the received (changed) information.